# How to count spectral clusters in a cosine similarity matrix?

Tags: python-3.x, cluster-analysis, cosine-similarity

Could someone please suggest an approach to identify and count the distinct cluster segments within a cosine similarity matrix?

For the attached visualization of a matrix I would expect the count to be 8.  An easy task for the human eye but seemingly exceptionally challenging to accomplish in code.

None of my attempts using scikit-learn have come even close feeling like I'm using the wrong tool for the job and would really appreciate a sanity check.

[image: Cosine Similarity Matrix]